# Split a PHP array into a string

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like the one below, which actually collects login and other data from a user submitted form, to be written to a DB. I don't need all the form data, and hence this approach.

```
$array['a']  = $_POST['userName'];
$array['a'] .= $_POST['passWord'];
```

Which results in:

```
$array['a']  = 'username@example.com';
$array['a'] .= 'password';
```

I'm trying to get values from the array as a string, sperated by `,` or `::`, but just cannot figure how to do it.

Using implode gives me a continious string like `username@example.compassword`

`$comma_separated = implode($array);`
`echo $comma_separated;`

Is it somehow possible to get a string like `::username@example.com ::passpword` from the array without a for loop.

The approach cannot be changed since it's already in a working site.

I'm using PHP 7.0 on a Windows 10 Machine for testing.

Comment: You forgot the glue, http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues in your code:

1. wrong implementation of `implode()`;
2. Same `array` index

**How to achieve this result?**

```
::username@example.com ::password
```

**You can achieve this result by using this:**

```
// example with your code
$array['a']  = 'username@example.com';
$array['b'] = 'password';

echo "::".implode("::",$array);
```

**Result:**

```
::username@example.com::password
```

**Some Optimization:**

As you mentioned you are using form with `POST` method than you can use like that:

```
echo "::".implode("::",$_POST); //::username@example.com::password
```

**Few Suggestion:**

Add `error_reporting` at the top of the file for getting errors.

[Error Reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

Learn how `implode()` function works

[PHP Implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

Answer (score 1):

You can use implode. It combines items of array with given `parameter` and returns a string. Here is the documentation of [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).

> Returns a string containing a string representation of all the array
>   elements in the same order, with the glue string between each element.

```
$array  = ['username@example.com', 'password'];
$string = implode(',', $array);
echo $string;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo ":: ".implode("::",$a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way

```
$array[]  = 'username@example.com';
$array[] = 'password'
echo '::'.implode('::', $array);
```

output

```
::username@example.com::password
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use implode like this.

```
$array[]  = $_POST['userName'];
$array[]  = $_POST['passWord'];

echo implode(',',$array);
```